# boost vector serialization append issue

Tags: c++, vector, boost-serialization

Consider the following example:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>


#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);



    vector<int> src1 = {1}, src2 = {2};

    vector<int> dst;

    oa << src1;
    oa << src2;

    string serialized = oss.str();
    std::istringstream iss(serialized);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);


    ia >> dst;

    cout << "size=" << dst.size() << endl;

    ia >> dst;
    cout << "size=" << dst.size() << endl;
}
```

Output:
size=1
size=1

Everything is fine. However if change vector<int> to vector<string>:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>


#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);


    vector<string> src1 = {"hi"}, src2 = {"hi"};

    vector<string> dst;


    oa << src1;
    oa << src2;

    string serialized = oss.str();
    std::istringstream iss(serialized);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);


    ia >> dst;

    cout << "size=" << dst.size() << endl;

    ia >> dst;
    cout << "size=" << dst.size() << endl;
}
```

Output:
size=1
size=2

Result is appended to dst, not assigned. Why? How "assign semantic" can be achieved?

compiler: gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2)
compilation: g++ -std=c++11 test2.cc -lboost_serialization

Comment: On MSVC2013 works as you expect.

Comment: Which version of BOOST are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is following code at sources of boost 1.58.

```
if(detail::is_default_constructible<U>()){
    t.resize(count);
    typename std::vector<U, Allocator>::iterator hint;
    hint = t.begin();
    while(count-- > 0){
        ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("item", *hint++);
    }
}
else{
    t.reserve(count);
    while(count-- > 0){
        detail::stack_construct<Archive, U> u(ar, item_version);
        ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("item", u.reference());
        t.push_back(u.reference());
        ar.reset_object_address(& t.back() , & u.reference());
     }
}
```

And `detail::is_default_constructible` returns `false` for `std::string` (for some reasons `boost::has_trivial_constructor` is used) and `true` for `int`. So, when `U` is `int`, `resize` will be called and then value assignment will be used, but when `U` is `std::string` `reserve` will be used (reserve don't actually resize container) and then `push_back` will be used.

Simple workaround will be just `clear` vector before second read from archive.

```
ia >> dst;

cout << "size=" << dst.size() << endl;

dst.clear();
ia >> dst;
cout << "size=" << dst.size() << endl;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I`ve already looked through boost sources and realized this behavior. But I don`t understand why boost developers choose such strange semantic